# Is there any way to disable the case sensitive option for the particular mysql database till next restart?

Tags: mysql, innodb, case-sensitive

MySQL (Version 5.7.24 on Ubuntu 16.04 with lower_case_table_names as
0) : Following Query returns error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column
>   'K.fieldname' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT *
FROM mytab k 
WHERE K.fieldname IS NULL;
```

(InnoDB) table mytab's Alies name is in lower case(k) and fieldname is
referenced by upper case (K) letter.

Is there any option to resolve this without changing the code or my.cnf settings (like set variables sessionwise or tablewise ...).

Comment: Is there any particular reason that prevents you from typing the column name as it's defined? Why do you need to make it work bad to make it work? Why can't you simply provide info as it's expected by the software?

Comment: wrongly entered in the middleware and verified with the case insensitive env. now it is in case sensitive env. So, try to solve this issue without change the middleware but db side.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error you are receiving has nothing to do with the `lower_case_table_names` parameter setting. It is clearly mentioned in the [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

> **Note**
>
> Although database, table, and trigger names are not case sensitive on
>   some platforms, you should not refer to one of these using different
>   cases within the same statement. The following statement would not
>   work because it refers to a table both as my_table and as MY_TABLE:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MY_TABLE.col=1;
> ```

So, you have no other solution, other than fixing your query and use identical case for the alias throughout the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytab k 
WHERE k.fieldname IS NULL;  /* <-- use small k here */
```

Comment: According to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) , they mention that If lower_case_table_names  set to 1, table names are stored in lowercase on disk and **comparisons are not case sensitive**. Don't you think it is related to lower_case_table_names ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  In another environment where we have lower_case_table_names is set as 1 allows this query to execute and returns the values properly.